# SharePoint File Sharing Options disabled

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, office-365

Techies,

The current user is having full permission on the SharePoint online site, still unable to see the sharing options such as "People in the organization with the link" and "Specific People". not sure why it's.

I'm using the custom permission level on the owner group

Please shed some ideas

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Manage Permissions" under site permissions is unchecked, which causes the other Sharing options to be disabled

The underlying thing is while using share with anyone in the organization or specific person, unique permissions will be created, when the user doesn't have permission to manage permissions in the site permissions enabled, then the user won't see the options enabled

Answer (score 0):

You should enable external sharing in both tenant and site collection level.

1.Tenant level:

SharePoint admin center -> Polices -> Sharing -> Set “Least permissive” as Anyone.

2.Site level:

SharePoint admin center -> Active site -> Find your site -> Sharing -> Set “External sharing” as Anyone.

There is [the similar post](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/59054/unable-to-share-files-outside-of-my-organization-w.html) on the Q&A Forum, I suggest you can follow the progress of the post.

Comment: I'm not asking for "Anyone with link" - I know this is to be dealt with external sharing.

I'm asking why other options are disabled

Comment: I want to confirm that whether the user in the owner group with custom permission?

Comment: yes the user is in the owner group with custom permission

Comment: Per my test, it caused by the custom permission. If the user with default full control permission, then he can share the file sharing options are enabled.

Comment: The key level which makes other sharing options disabled is "Manage Permissions"